# After HTML parsing (using HTML::TreeBuilder) image get corrupted

Tags: image, perl, html-parsing

im building a small proxy for my own use with LWP::UserAgent and then i'm parsing the HTML using HTML::TreeBuilder

depending on the page i am, my code loads a small module that get info / change display and then i print my HTML again.

At the beginning, i was just loading HTML::TreeBuilder inside my module, modifying there, and printint back the HTML from there, everything was fine.

Now i'm building the tree in the code that call the small module, (the small module still modify it) and print the HTML from here, and all image got the error (from firebug) Image corrupt or truncated, and dont load.

Here is simplified code i use.

Not working code :

```
$info{content}=$response->content;
$info{tree} = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($info{content}) or die $!;

do module.pm #modify the tree

$info{content} = $info{tree}->as_HTML(undef,"\t");
$info{tree}->delete();

return \$info{content};
```

and in the module.pm

```
my $elem = $info{tree}->look_down(_tag => "img");
$elem->attr('width', '240');
$elem->attr('height', '60');
```

And the working code

```
$info{content}=$response->content;

do module.pm #modify the tree

return \$info{content};
```

in the module :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder; # Ensure weak references in use

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($awproxy::process::info{content}) or die $!;

my $elem = $tree->look_down(_tag => "img");
$elem->attr('width', '240');
$elem->attr('height', '60');

$awproxy::process::info{content} = $tree->as_HTML(undef,"\t");
$tree->delete();

1;
```

Anyone has an idea where it could come from?

And the HTML returned from both code is exactly the same

edit : all the codes i use.

main.pm called by perltranshandler

```
package awproxy::main;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Apache2::Const qw(:common);
use Apache2::RequestRec;
use Apache2::RequestIO;
use awproxy::process;

my $destdomain="domain.com";
my $desthost="www1.domain.com";
my $wwwdesthost="www.domain.com";

sub handler {
   my ($r) = @_;
   $r->handler("perl-script");
   $r->set_handlers(PerlHandler => \&proxy_handler);
   return OK;
}

sub proxy_handler {
    my($r) = @_;
    $r->status(200);
    $r->content_type("text/plain");
    my $ourhost="aw.mydomain.fr.cr";
    my $wwwourhost="awww.mydomain.fr.cr";
    my $result=awproxy::process::process($r);

    my $dest;
    my $headers_in = $r->headers_in;
    my $host=$headers_in->get("Host");
    if($host=~/^www\.a/) { # matches $wwwourhost
        $dest=$wwwdesthost;
    } else {
        $dest=$desthost;
    }

# filter headers_out as with ProxyPassReverse
   my $h=$r->headers_out();
   foreach my $k (qw(Content-Location Location URI)) {
      my $l=$h->get($k);
      if($l && ( $l=~s!(http://)$desthost!$1$ourhost! || $l=~s!(http://)$wwwdesthost!$1$wwwourhost!)) {
         $h->set($k,$l);
      }
   }
# cookie reverse modification
   for my $k ("Set-Cookie") {
      my @l=$h->get($k);
      foreach my $cookie (@l) {
         if($cookie=~s/$desthost/$ourhost/ || $cookie=~s/$wwwdesthost/$wwwourhost/ || $cookie=~s/domain=$destdomain/host=$ourhost/) {
            $h->add($k, $cookie);
         }
      }
   }

    if($result) {
        $r->print($$result);
    }
    $_=undef; # clear private data
    undef %awproxy::process::info;
   return OK;
}

1;
```

the process called by the previous function

```
package awproxy::process;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Apache2::Connection; #permet de recup l'ip
use LWP::UserAgent; #pour les connexion
use APR::Table;
use DBI;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;


sub process {   
    my $desthost="www1.domain.com";
    my $wwwdesthost="www.domain.com";
    my $ourhost="aw.mydomain.fr.cr";
    my $wwwourhost="awww.mydomain.fr.cr";
    my $destdomain="aw.mydomain.fr.cr";
    my $dir="/usr/lib/perl5/awproxy/";
    our %info;

    my $r = shift;

    our $dbh=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX'
               ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";


    #pour recup l'ip
    my $c=$r->connection();
    my $ip=$c->remote_ip();

    # autodetect $ourhost value from input headers
    my $headers_in = $r->headers_in;
    my $host=$headers_in->get("Host");
    my $dest;
    if($host=~/^www\.a/) { # matches $wwwourhost
        $dest=$wwwdesthost;
    } else {
        $dest=$desthost;
    }

    #Pour creer la requete
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    $ua->agent('Mwoua/proxy');
    my $method = uc($r->method);
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new($method,"http://".$dest.$r->unparsed_uri); 


    while(my($key,$val) = each %$headers_in) {
      next if($key eq "Host"); # do not override host header
      next if($key eq "Accept-Encoding");
      $request->header($key,$val);
    }
    #on ajoute l'ip
    if(!$request->header("X-Forwarded-For"))
    {
        $request->header("X-Forwarded-For", $ip);
        $request->header("X-Forwarded-Host", $headers_in->{Host});
    }

    #on ajoute les donnees POST
    if($request->header("Content-Length")) {
        my $postdata;
        $r->read($postdata,$request->header("Content-Length"));
        $request->content($postdata);       
    }


    my $response = $ua->request($request);
    if(!$response)
    {
        $r->status(500);
        $r->print("sorry: something went wrong on the aw-side of proxy\n");
        return;
    }
    $r->content_type($response->header('Content-type'));
    my $headers_out=[];
    $response->scan(sub {
        if(lc $_[0] ne "connection") {
                $r->headers_out->add(@_);
                push(@$headers_out, \@_);
        }
    });
    #Ce dont les modules peuvent avoir besoin
    $info{setcookie}=$response->header('Set-Cookie');
    $info{content}=$response->content;  

    #On modifie les liens   
    $info{content}=~s!(http-equiv="refresh"[^>]*url=http://)$desthost!$1$ourhost!i;
    $info{content}=~s!(http-equiv="refresh"[^>]*url=http://)$wwwdesthost!$1$wwwourhost!i;
    $info{content}=~s!(<a[^>]* href="?http://)$desthost!$1$ourhost!gi;
    $info{content}=~s!(<a[^>]* href="?http://)$wwwdesthost!$1$wwwourhost!gi;
    $info{content}=~s!(<img[^>]* src="?http://)$desthost!$1$ourhost!gi;
    $info{content}=~s!(<form action="?http://)$desthost!$1$ourhost!gi;

    #$info{tree} = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($info{content}) or die $!;   

    #on regarde ou on est, et on applique les modifs
    my $include=$r->uri;

    if($info{content} =~ m!<b>Security Measure</b>! )
    {
        $include=$dir."security.pm";
    }
    else
    {
        $include =~ s/\.php$//i ;
        $include =~ s/\/$// ;
        $include=$dir.$dest.$include.'.pm';
    }
    #$info{content}=$include.$info{content};
    if(-e $include)
    {
        require $include; #same with do $include;
    }
    #$info{content} = $info{tree}->as_HTML(undef,"    ");
    $dbh->disconnect();
    undef $dbh;
    #$info{tree}->delete();
    #undef $info{tree};
    return \$info{content};
}
1;
```

and the module i'm doing my test with at the moment :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder; # Ensure weak references in use

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($awproxy::process::info{content}) or die $!;

my $elem = $tree->look_down(_tag => "img");
$elem->attr('width', '240');
$elem->attr('height', '60');

$awproxy::process::info{content} = $tree->as_HTML(undef,"\t");
$tree->delete();
```

Note : this is the working version, you can easily change it to the non working version with the info i provided at the beginning (create tree in process.pm and use this created tree or the modification in the other module)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in how your proxy handles the HTML - as you say, the HTML is identical from both code forms - but how the image data is handled. After the browser has done a `GET` for the HTML it will go ahead and do the same for the constituent parts - JavaScript, CSS, images etc. - and your proxy must pass these on correctly as well. Clearly it isn't doing so.

It is also worth saying that Perl `*.pm` modules are meant to be `use`d, and `do` isn't a good way to do much at all. You should decide whether you want your module to be object-oriented or a simple subclass of `Exporter` and tidy things up.

You should also call `as_HTML` like this

```
$tree->as_HTML('<>&', '  ')
```

as you *must* encode at least those symbols, and tabs are a little arcane for use as indentation.

Comment: Well, the module called depend on the page that is proxied, can exporter allow that? (i.e a piece of code executed depending on a paramater).
I have several function for everypage that i proxy, so i would not prefer create a file with just function and include them.

And do you have any idea why the GET of the image doesnt work (the css is gotten fine)?

Comment: @David Levy:  Without seeing your code I can't really help. On the face of it I don't see why you can't put everything that is in your current module into a subroutine and export that. Similarly I can't tell why your proxy isn't passing on the image properly without sight of your code. It is binary data whereas the HTML and CSS are probably plain ASCII - are you mishandling binary data? I suggest you post your code so that we can help better.

Comment: All the code are in my first post, if you have time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I understood why it doesnt work.

In my workin case, I was parsing only html page. In my non working case, it was trying to parse everything that was proxied (images included).

So to make it work, I added this :

```
if($r->uri =~ /\.png$|\.jpg$/i) 
{
    return \$info{content};
}
```

So now, it doesnt try to parse images, and it works fine.
(might need to add few things in the regex, but in my case there's only png and jpg)

edit : a test on the content type should be way better, something like that (not tested)

```
if($r->content_type =~ /text\/html/i )
{
    return \$info{content};
}
```